# Change font color to black when cell is activated

Tags: vba

I have a cell formatted with red font. I'd like for the format to change to black font when the user clicks on the cell, or navigates to it with the keyboard.

The cell is "Q15". I'd like the code to apply to all instances of "Q15" within the workbook--regardless of which sheet.

I have entered the following in "ThisWorkbook". How do I specify that I am referring to "Q15" in all worksheets?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    Target.Font.ColorIndex = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook module` is correct place where you need to add your code.

However, you need to use different kind of event. Use the one in the following (complete) code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$Q$15" Then

        Target.Font.ColorIndex = 1

    End If
End Sub
```